# PowerShell 2.0,Get-ADComputer Script Issues (no output)

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-2.0

I am trying to use the script below to test the trust relationship with the domain controller for every computer in AD. I am using powershell 2.0. When I test the script I get no output. It is based off a powershell 4.0 script that works.

```
    $localCredential = Get-Credential

ForEach ($Name in Get-AdComputer -Filter *){

   $output = { $Name = $_.Name }

   if (-not (Test-Connection $Name $_.Name -Quiet -Count 1)) { $output.Status = 'Offline'
   } else {
       $trustStatus = Invoke-Command $Name $_.Name -ScriptBlock { Test-ComputerSecureChannel } -Credential $localCredential
       $output.Status = $trustStatus
   }

   [pscustomobject]$output

}
```

Below is a powershell 4.0 script that I have tried to convert because the .ForEach syntax is not valid in Powershell 2.0.

Source: https://adamtheautomator.com/trust-relationship-between-this-workstation-and-the-primary-domain-failed/

here is the working script I tried to convert from:

```
    $localCredential = Get-Credential

@(Get-AdComputer -Filter *).foreach({

   $output = @{ ComputerName = $_.Name }

   if (-not (Test-Connection -ComputerName $_.Name -Quiet -Count 1)) { $output.Status = 'Offline'
   } else {
       $trustStatus = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $_.Name -ScriptBlock { Test-ComputerSecureChannel } -Credential $localCredential
       $output.Status = $trustStatus
   }

   [pscustomobject]$output

})
```

Does anyone know why I am not getting an output? Is there something clearly wrong with the first script I posted? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you very much,

Dave

Comment: PS Version 2 is deprecated (all OSes that come with PS version 2 are out of support now). Converting a script written for PS4 to PS2 is not advisable without extensive knowledge about PS2 and up to date versions. PSCustomObject (which you use in your script) is for PS3+, same with the Foreach you encountered earlier. My advise is: Update at least WMF to a newer version or just use an up to date Windows machine to run the commands from (you can install the AD Cmdlets on a Windows 10 machine or just proxy a session to a DC with new-pssession and then import-pssession) to run them locally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `foreach()` statement you declare the iterator variable `$Name`, but inside the loop body you inconsistently use `$_` as well.

You're also using `[pscustomobject]@{}`, a special object allocation syntax that was introduced in PowerShell 3.0 - you need to use `New-Object psobject -Property` in version 2.0.

Finally, your `$output` variable needs to be a dictionary and not a scriptblock (notice the `@` in front of `{ Name = ... }`).

To fix it all:

```
ForEach ($Computer in Get-AdComputer -Filter *){

   $output = @{ Name = $Computer.Name }

   if (-not (Test-Connection $Computer.Name -Quiet -Count 1)) {
       $output.Status = 'Offline'
   } else {
       $trustStatus = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Computer.Name -ScriptBlock { Test-ComputerSecureChannel } -Credential $localCredential
       $output.Status = $trustStatus
   }

   New-Object psobject -Property $output
}
```